# Python pickle : Can't pickle <class 'interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator'>: it's not found as interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator

Tags: python, interpolation, pickle

I have an issue with the Pickle module in Python. I want to interpolate some 4-parameter data, so I want to build and store the interpolator, so that it can be reused in another code, without being re-generated at execution time. I'm actually losing a lot of time re-creating it at every execution of my code.
All I can get is this message:

> "PicklingError: Can't pickle :
>   it's not found as interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator"

I'm blowing my head off to try to figure out how to solve it, this is a simplified versione of my code (Python v2.7), and the traceback follows
Thanks in advance for your suggestions

```
a1,a2,a3,a4 = np.mgrid[paramvariation]
pts = np.array([a1.ravel(),a2.ravel(),a3.ravel(),a4.ravel()]).T
sr=paramvalues.ravel()
LinearNDInterp = interp.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator(pts,sr,fill)

fileid=open("try.out",'w')
pickle.dump(LinearNDInterp,fileid) 
fileid.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\startup.py", line 128, in runfile
execfile(filename, glbs)
File "tryout.py", line 516, in <module>
main("")
File "tryout.py", line 354, in main
pickle.dump(LinearNDInterp,fileid)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
self.save(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
save(args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
save(element)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
(obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator'>: it's not found as interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a recently fixed bug in SciPy:
[BUG: interpolate: make interpnd.* objects pickleable](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/7d1ecbd42db21f0ca50ab23999756c34c1d77723)

Comment: Thank you, I've followed the corrections highlighted in this bug review, but the error is still there... And the modified file generate_interpnd is not executed at all... Am I missing something?

Comment: That looks like a file that is executed during the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround is just to pickle the arguments of `LinearNDInterpolator`.

Comment: I already pickle the arguments, but that doesn't solve the problem: the interpolator has to be re-generated with these arguments at every execution